# Get NULL/empty columns in Laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Currently I'm working on a ajax search filters on Laravel, but I cannot get the correct info, this is the scenario:

I have 2 tables:

- Table1: SoftwareRequest
- Table2: DenyCategory

with a select option I get the name as Value

[image]

and I added that select option like in top of the query on the controller function:

```
$deniedReason = $request->get('deniedReason');
        if($deniedReason == "All"){
            $deniedReason = "";
        }
```

So that means that every time I select "All" it will be empty so I can get all data like empty **(this is the problem)**.

This is my current query:

```
$request_data = SoftwareRequest::leftJoin('DenyCategory', 'SoftwareRequest.DenyCategoryId', '=', 'DenyCategory.Id')->where('DenyCategory.Name', 'like', '%' . $deniedReason . '%')->paginate(20);
```

So the thing is that if I select another option rather than "All", for example "Already Available", I do get the excepted data, meaning all objects from table 1 joined with table 2 that has that option, but the problem comes when I select **"All"** it doesn't bring all the data it should and that's because not all objects have `DenyCategoryId` in Table1 meaning that some of those are Null/empty so it only brings the ones **'LIKE'** Null/empty as I specified on the previous code block.

```
$deniedReason = $request->get('deniedReason');
        if($deniedReason == "All"){
            $deniedReason = "";
        }
```

How can I get all data empty or not empty when I select the option All and as well as to get the data when I select another option? I bet it would have something to do with the query not being 'Like' but that's out of my knowledge scope.

Comment: Use `$request->input('deniedReason')`

Comment: hello @Sobir I do get the value of the input, the problem is that I need to get ALL including Null data from the joined column SoftwareRequest.DenyCategoryId with the table DenyCategory

Comment: is there a way to change the parent value to NotNull, for ex.

->leftJoin('DenyCategory', 'NOTNULL(SoftwareRequest.DenyCategoryId)', '=', 'DenyCategory.Id')

So I could only get the ones with data on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make the `where` clause optional?

```php
$queryBuilder = SoftwareRequest::leftJoin('DenyCategory', 'SoftwareRequest.DenyCategoryId', '=', 'DenyCategory.Id')

// Only apply where-clause when denied reason has been provided.
if ($request->get('deniedReason') !== 'All') {
    $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->where('DenyCategory.Name', 'like', '%' . $deniedReason . '%');
}

$request_data = $queryBuilder->paginate(20);
```

I think you can improve your code a bit better but I'll leave that up to you with some pointers:

- [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
- [Class Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

Comment: thanks, i'll try that. Hmm
is there a way to change the table1 value to NotNull on the leftJoin, for ex. ->leftJoin('DenyCategory', 'NOTNULL(SoftwareRequest.DenyCategoryId)', '=', 'DenyCategory.Id') So I could only get the ones with data on it

Comment: I tried what you said and worked as expected, thanks Danny